# .gitignore is being ignored by VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

Whenever I make changes to our .gitignore file, it never gets tracked by VSCode. It still wants to commit, or if I include them, still ignores. Why is VSCode not listening to my file and the changes that i make there?

[image: VScode screenshot of gitignore]

Comment: If the file that you added to .gitignore is already tracked, it makes no difference,... .gitignore only affects things that you haven't traccked (added, already part of the revision you are on) yet.

Comment: @eftshift0 But in this case it's not tracked, but I want to include it. Why isn't it?

Comment: If you change the file and git does not say anything about it, then it could be ignored (.gitignore can ask git to ignore .gitignore, of course) or you have asked index not to care fot it (with `git update-index --assume-unchanged`)

Comment: @eftshift0 I'm not sure if I understand. I didn't include .gitignore in the .gitignore of course. Normally, when you add or remove things it should update your changelog automatically in VSCode, no? Either adding or removing it from the commit. That's how I see it work with other people. What could be reasons that it is not doing that for me?

Comment: I don't know about VSCode. I would check what `git status` says.

Comment: @eftshift0 git status is clean, some rules do work in .gitignore, but many don't. For example this /Base.lproj. But I don't know why

Comment: How about `git status --ignored`?

Comment: Ah yes @eftshift0 there the file is present `ios/App/App/Base.lproj/`. But it should be excluded according to .gitignore

Comment: I managed to do it via phpstorm via the UI, but I don't really understand what is going on yet..